# merge two dataframe on a column with duplicate entries

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like:

```
col1   col2   
1      a
1      b
2      c
```

and

```
col1   col3   
1      d
1      e
3      f
```

how can I merge them (on col1) to get the following?

```
col1   col2   col3
1      a      d
1      b      e
2      c      Nan
3      Nan    f
```

I tried pd.merge but it didn't give the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df1['key'] = df1.groupby('col1').cumcount()
df2['key'] = df2.groupby('col1').cumcount()

res = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'key'], how='outer').drop('key', 1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    a    d
1     1    b    e
2     2    c  NaN
3     3  NaN    f
```

The idea of the `groupby('col1').cumcount()` is to create a unique key for the repeated elements.